# Looping through all the cells in a datagridview

Tags: c#, graphics, datagridview

This is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Blue);
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            float p1x = float.Parse(dr.Cells["p1x"].Value.ToString());
            float p1y = float.Parse(dr.Cells["p1y"].Value.ToString());
            float p2x = float.Parse(dr.Cells["p2x"].Value.ToString());
            float p2y = float.Parse(dr.Cells["p2y"].Value.ToString());
            g.DrawEllipse(p, p1x, p1y, 10, 10);
            g.DrawEllipse(p, p2x, p2y, 10, 10);
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, p1x, p1y, 10, 10);
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, p2x, p2y, 10, 10);
            g.DrawLine(p, p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y);
        }
    }
```

On executing the above code, I'm getting the runtime exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
Please help.

Comment: Well, which object is null? Stick a breakpoint in it and see which line throws, and if any of your variables are null.

Comment: **One of the cell values** is *null*.

Comment: @KingKing Exactly sir, this is what i just found out. How to detect that empty cell value before the exception arises?

Comment: @RuchirSharma you can use some `if` statement to check if it is `null` or not, you can also use the short syntax: `(dr.Cells["p1x"].Value ?? "0").ToString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely one of your cells has a null value i.e.

`dr.Cells["p1x"].Value == null`

You can't use `ToString()` on `null` so you get that error.